# WCF : Is inactivityTimeout effective when reliableSession enabled="false"

Tags: wcf

If I have this configuration:

```
      <reliableSession
        ordered="true"            
        inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
        enabled="false" />
```

Is the inactivityTimeout effective (even if reliableSession is not enabled)?

EDIT : If is not effective, can you control inactivity timeout elsewhere?

Thanks

Comment: What inactivity ?? The inactivityTimeout only controls the time a session can be inactive before being terminated; if you have reliableSession = false, there is no session - so it can't time out....

Comment: What it the client does not close/dispose the proxy? It will keep a connection open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer in the [MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.binding.receivetimeout.aspx). The receiveTimeout of the Binding element is also an inactivity timeout. When reliableSession is enabled both values are effective.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that this is used unless you use reliable session.

You can set the timeout on the binding, there is a sendtimeout, closetimeout ....